# Protect a string buffer from two threads?

Tags: multithreading, string, delphi, buffer, indy

I am working with streaming packet strings through Indy sockets, and on the client side, I have a thread which reads incoming data from the `TIdTCPClient` and continuously appending this data to the end of a single string buffer. I have another thread which is continuously reading this buffer from the beginning, copying (and deleting) data as necessary (one complete packet at a time).

I know that in any case two threads accessing the same variable can be dangerous. But does this apply to strings too? Or just objects? Can I feel safe with this reading/writing of the same string from two different threads? If not, then what should I do to protect this string? This is a plain string called `FBuffer`.

I'm appending data to the end like so:

```
procedure TListenThread.CheckForData;
begin
  if FClientSocket.Connected then begin
    FClientSocket.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(5000);
    if not FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      FBuffer:= FBuffer + FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString;
  end;
end;
```

And the other thread is reading it like so:

```
procedeure TPacketThread.CheckForPacket;
var
  P: Integer; //Deliminator position
  T: String;  //Temp copying string
  Z: Integer; //Expected packet size
begin
  P:= Pos('#', FBuffer);
  if P > 0 then begin //Is the deliminator found?
    T:= Copy(FBuffer, 1, P-1); //Copy up to deliminator...
    Z:= StrToIntDef(T, 0); //Convert packet size to integer...
    if Z > 0 then begin
      //Is there a full packet waiting in buffer?
      if Length(FBuffer) >= Z then begin
        //First, delete size definition and deliminator...
        Delete(FBuffer, 1, P);
        //Now grab the rest of it up to the packet size...
        T:= Copy(FBuffer, 1, Z);
        //Delete what we just copied...
        Delete(FBuffer, 1, Z);
        //Finally, pass this packet string for further processing...
        ProcessPacket(T);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code is a simplified version of my code just to demonstrate all the work I need to do with `FBuffer`.

Comment: FBuffer is a regular `string`?

Comment: @WarrenP Yes, just a regular string.

Comment: It's more usual to load data into some Tbuffer object and queue that off to the processing thread on a producer-consumer queue.  As soon as you queue one Tbuffer instance off, create a new one.  That completely avoids the huge pile of steamy, messy code associated with shared strings etc.  That, and eliminating the grossly wasteful polling for new data.  That, and eliminating false-sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must protect the string buffer from concurrent access.  Indy has a `TIdThreadSafeString` class you can use for that purpose, eg:

```
FBuffer: TIdThreadSafeString;
// make sure to Create() and Free() as needed..
```

.

```
procedure TListenThread.CheckForData; 
begin 
  if FClientSocket.Connected then begin 
    FClientSocket.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(5000); 
    if not FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then 
      FBuffer.Append(FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString);
  end; 
end;
```

.

```
procedure TPacketThread.CheckForPacket; 
var 
  P: Integer; //Deliminator position 
  T: String;  //Temp copying string 
  Z: Integer; //Expected packet size 
begin 
  FBuffer.Lock;
  try
    P:= Pos('#', FBuffer.Value); 
    if P > 0 then begin //Is the deliminator found? 
      T := Copy(FBuffer.Value, 1, P-1); //Copy up to deliminator... 
      Z := StrToIntDef(T, 0); //Convert packet size to integer... 
      if Z > 0 then begin 
        //Is there a full packet waiting in buffer? 
        if Length(FBuffer.Value) >= Z then begin 
          //First, delete size definition and deliminator... 
          FBuffer.Value := Copy(FBuffer.Value, P+1, MaxInt); 
          //Now grab the rest of it up to the packet size... 
          T := Copy(FBuffer.Value, 1, Z); 
          //Delete what we just copied... 
          FBuffer.Value := Copy(FBuffer.Value, Z+1, MaxInt); 
          //Finally, pass this packet string for further processing... 
          ProcessPacket(T); 
        end; 
      end; 
    end; 
  finally
    FBuffer.Unlock;
  end;
end;
```

With that said, given what you have shown about the packet formatting, I would take a different tactic instead:

```
FBuffer: TIdThreadSafeStringList;
// make sure to Create() and Free() as needed..
```

.

```
procedure TListenThread.CheckForData; 
var 
  T: String;  //Temp copying string 
  Z: Integer; //Expected packet size 
begin 
  if FClientSocket.Connected then begin 
    if FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
      FClientSocket.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(5000);
      if FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
    end; 
    // data is available, keep reading as long as packets are present...
    repeat
      T := FClientSocket.IOHandler.ReadLn('#');
      Z := StrToIntDef(T, 0);
      if Z > 0 then begin 
        T := FClientSocket.IOHandler.ReadString(Z); 
        FBuffer.Add(T); 
      end; 
    until FClientSocket.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty;
  end; 
end;
```

.

```
procedure TPacketThread.CheckForPacket; 
var 
  L: TStringList;
  T: String;
begin 
  L := FBuffer.Lock;
  try
    if L.Count = 0 then Exit;
    T := L[0];
    L.Delete(0);
  finally
    FBuffer.Unlock;
  end;
  ProcessPacket(T); 
end;
```

Comment: `ReadLn('#');` This will erase the number from the client's input buffer, suppose a packet is thousands of bytes, if all the data isn't available yet, then this number would be gone for the next time this is executed. Is there a way to read this without deleting it from the buffer? Otherwise, I would have to set some sort of read state property in this thread, store this number also, and the next time the thread executes, if check this read state, etc...

Comment: @JerryDodge Indy Read operations block until all data has been received (for example up to the terminator or the expected number of bytes), so your code will not have to handle 'unavailable' data (except timeouts).

Comment: Exactly. `ReadLn()` will wait for the `'#'` character to arrive before exiting. `ReadString()` will wait until the specified number of bytes arrives before exiting. The only thing that would affect that is if you have assigned a `ReadTimeout` value. If `ReadLn()` times out, it will return a blank string, leaving all of the current data in the InputBuffer, and `ReadString()` will not be called since `StrToIntDef()` will return 0. If `ReadString()` times out, it will raise an `EIdReadTimeout` exception, in which case you should probably reset your connection anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you must protect the strings when are accessed from multiples threads, you can do that using crtical sections. Take a look to the [EnterCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [LeaveCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , [InitializeCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [DeleteCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Comment: So presumably I could build a small class around this string, with for example a procedure `AddToBuffer(const S: String);` where I do `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection` in a `try..finally` block (and same for reading data), right?

Comment: You don't need create a new procedure you can include the calls to the `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` methods directly in your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know about `TIdThreadSafeString`, I just answer the question in a more general context.

Comment: I was referring to @JerryDoge's question about "building a small class around this string".  Indy already does that.